# Can Tamron 16-300mm lens fit on a Canon 700D?

Tags: canon, tamron, lens-recommendation

I want to buy a new lens that extends my zoom range, because the one came with the camera is 18-55mm with a small zoom range.  The specifications for the Tamron lens look good, with a great zoom range, and also can be used as macro lens, for portraits and travel - I will not have to carry more than one lens & switch lenses. It's within my budget too.

So can anybody help me to know if it can fit my camera?  Is it good enough or I can find something with same specifications & same price range in another brand that's better?

Answer (score 0):

No limitation, providing the correct mount is chosen. Here is amazon link for Canon mount http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00JM15OCW

Alternatives

- Canon EF 70-300mm f/4-5.6 IS USM, £ 299.00  however that will not cover 18-70mm
- Canon EF 75-300mm f/4-5.6 III USM, £ 129.00
- Tamron 28-300MM F/3.5-6.3 Di VC PZD, £ 489.00, but not macro
- Tamron 18-270mm F/3.5-6.3 Di II VC PZD, £ 269.00, no macro

Comment: -1 for claiming that the 75-300 is an upgrade.

Comment: @PhilipKendall corrected, I think I was looking on older version of 70-300 but mentioned 75-300. Sorry my bad

Comment: I *want* to give you -1 for even mentioning the 75-300!

Comment: @MichaelClark there is no concept for happiness for all, sorry. Maybe you can provide suggestions for given the price tag and requirements

Comment: The 75-300 is a really *bad* lens. For a crop body such as the 700D the latest versions of the 55-250 are much better lenses and values. But there is no specific price range given in the question.